# How can I hold Twitter Bootstrap Popover open until my mouse moves into it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, popover

I have a link that uses the [Twitter Bootstrap Popover version 1.3.0](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/twitter-bootstrap-popover) to show some information.  This information includes a link, but every-time I move my mouse from the link to the popover, the popover just disappears.

How can I hold popover open long enough to enable the mouse to move into it?  Then when the mouse moves out of the link and popover, hide it?

Or is there some other plugin that can do this?

Comment: I know you already solved your issue, but in order for this to be helpful to future readers, please post some relevant code so it makes sense.

Comment: In your question?  I see no code in the question.

Comment: I'm not talking about the code in your answer... I'm talking about putting something more meaningful in your question above.  This site is for the benefit of future readers as well as yourself.  Your question should be formatted in such a way that it makes sense and that so _somebody_ knows what you mean and could possibly figure it out.

Comment: I added a link to your question so at least the reader knows what plugin you're talking about.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Now I just switch to webuiPopover, it just works.

Comment: Sorry but even that was the way you end deciding is not the solution for the problem you presented and marking your own answer as the correct one when is not even using bootstrap to solve it, there is at least 3 solutions on this post that really solve the problem...

Answer (score 31):

With bootstrap (tested with version 2) I figured out the following code:

```
$("a[rel=popover]")
            .popover({
                offset: 10,
                trigger: 'manual',
                animate: false,
                html: true,
                placement: 'left',
                template: '<div class="popover" onmouseover="$(this).mouseleave(function() {$(this).hide(); });"><div class="arrow"></div><div class="popover-inner"><h3 class="popover-title"></h3><div class="popover-content"><p></p></div></div></div>'

            }).click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault() ;
            }).mouseenter(function(e) {
                $(this).popover('show');
            });
```

The main point is to override template with mouseleave() enabler. I hope this helps.

Comment: This worked for me. I wish this feature were built-in better so you don't have to pass this verbose 'template' option. The 'template' option isn't even documented at http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#popovers.

Comment: works but if you leave the container which triggers the popover it stays there until you hover the popover itself.

Comment: Probably was broken with the latest version of bootstrap

Comment: Doesn't work correctly with Bootstrap 3.0.0 and above. The solution I posted works in **Bootstrap 3.0.0 and above**, and is very easy to setup. Check it out [**HERE**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23820526/1799136)

Comment: I was googling for popover blinking and the only thing I missed was `offset: 10`. Thank you.

Comment: Check out @Fizzix's answer. It's by far the best solution.

Answer (score 28):

## Bootstrap 3 and above

Simple, just use the `container` option and have it as the element that is calling the popover. This way, the popover is a child of the element that calls it. Hence, you are technically still hovering over the parent, because the child popover belongs to it.

For example:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="pop" data-content="Testing 12345">This has a popover</div>
<div class="pop" data-content="Testing 12345">This has a popover</div>
<div class="pop" data-content="Testing 12345">This has a popover</div>
```

**jQuery:**

Running an `$.each()` loop over every one of my elements that I want a popover binded to its parent. In this case, each element has the class of `pop`.

```
$('.pop').each(function () {
    var $elem = $(this);
    $elem.popover({
        placement: 'top',
        trigger: 'hover',
        html: true,
        container: $elem
    });
});
```

**CSS:**

This part is optional, but recommended. It moves the popover down by 7 pixels for easier access.

```
.pop .popover {
    margin-top:7px;
}
```

[**WORKING DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/dLQQL/)

Comment: By far the easiest solution. Thanks!

Comment: By binding it to the element, the popover will be bound by the element's parent's overflow rules. Meaning if it exceeds the bounds and overflow is anything other than 'visible', then the user will need to scroll to view the popover, which is very unpleasant. This method is fine as long as your popover is not big or a parent element doesn't constrict its overflow.

Comment: @casey - You're absolutely correct. In a case like that, they would need to use a manual trigger instead. Although, can't see that happening too often. Been using this solution for quite a while now, and have never needed to use a manual trigger.

Comment: Very elegant. Very effective. Great answer.

Comment: Why do you use a double $($( ))? And thanks, this solution is great.

Comment: @Arad - Just a typo, thanks for letting me know. Will fix it now :)

Answer (score 26):

Just to add to Marchello's example, if you want the popover to disappear if the user moves their mouse away from the popover *and* source link, try this out.

```
var timeoutObj;
$('.nav_item a').popover({
    offset: 10,
    trigger: 'manual',
    html: true,
    placement: 'right',
    template: '<div class="popover" onmouseover="clearTimeout(timeoutObj);$(this).mouseleave(function() {$(this).hide();});"><div class="arrow"></div><div class="popover-inner"><h3 class="popover-title"></h3><div class="popover-content"><p></p></div></div></div>'
}).mouseenter(function(e) {
    $(this).popover('show');
}).mouseleave(function(e) {
    var ref = $(this);
    timeoutObj = setTimeout(function(){
        ref.popover('hide');
    }, 50);
});
```

Comment: This worked really well. Instead of setting options for each popup in javascript, you can add the offset, trigger, html, and placement directly into the html on `data` properties.

Comment: why am getting error says " timeoutObj is not defined" when move into the popover

Comment: What version of bootstrap/jquery are you using? Did you copy the code verbatim? If not, paste your code and I can try to help.

Comment: I got this `Uncaught ReferenceError: timeoutObj is not defined `

Comment: @andi Depending on your code, timeoutObj may be out of scope.

Answer (score 19):

This is a little hacky, but building off of marchello's example, I did this (no need for template):

```
$(".trigger-link").popover({
  trigger: "manual",
}).on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
}).on("mouseenter", function() {
  var _this = this;
  $(this).popover("show");
  $(this).siblings(".popover").on("mouseleave", function() {
    $(_this).popover('hide');
  });
}).on("mouseleave", function() {
  var _this = this;
  setTimeout(function() {
    if (!$(".popover:hover").length) {
      $(_this).popover("hide")
    }
  }, 100);
});
```

The `setTimeout` helps ensure that there's time to travel from the trigger link to the popover.

Comment: Thank you. I tried every answer on this page and yours is the only one that worked. You are awesome.

Comment: Really like your solution! I am using ```$this.data('popover').tip()``` instead of ```$(this).siblings(".popover")```, but it feels as hacky as your approach :) . Your setTimeout function with the hover selector is pretty smart!

Comment: Better to replace `$(this).hide();` with `$(_this).popover('hide');`

Comment: After some endless hours of googling, this made my day. thanks @clem

Comment: @lacco how can i use that $this.data('popover').tip() ?

Comment: BOOTSTRAP 3 NOTE: In BS3 they changed it to bs.popover instead of popover. Example : $('#anElement').data('bs.popover')

Answer (score 11):

[This issue on the bootstrap github](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/512) repo deals with this problem. fat pointed out the experimental "in top/bottom/left/right" placement. It works, pretty well, but you have to make sure the popover trigger is not positioned statically with css. Otherwise the popover won't appear where you want it to.

HTML:

`<span class="myClass" data-content="lorem ipsum content" data-original-title="pop-title">Hover me to show a popover.</span>`

CSS:

```
/*CSS */
.myClass{ position: relative;}
```

JS:

```
$(function(){
  $('.myClass').popover({placement: 'in top'});
});
```

Comment: Works for me! Tested on Chrome and Firefox.
However I got some inconsistencies with how the content of the popover is displayed, as fat warns in one of the issue's comment

Comment: great, this works for me, thanks - this is almost as neat as built in:)

Comment: If you're looking for a good alternative to bootstrap's popover that includes more customization, check out http://stevenbenner.github.com/jquery-powertip/

Answer (score 5):

Solution worked for us for Bootstrap 3.

```
var timeoutObj;
$('.list-group a').popover({
    offset: 10,
    trigger: 'manual',
    html: true,
    placement: 'right',
    template: '<div class="popover" onmouseover="$(this).mouseleave(function() {$(this).hide();});"><div class="arrow"></div><div class="popover-inner"><h3 class="popover-title"></h3><div class="popover-content"><p></p></div></div></div>'
}).mouseenter(function(e) {
    $(this).popover('show');
}).mouseleave(function(e) {
    var _this = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
        if (!$(".popover:hover").length) {
            $(_this).popover("hide");
        }
    }, 100);
});
```

Comment: Works quite well. Although, when your mouse leaves from the popover, it will not fade away. When your mouse leaves from the trigger, it will fade away. Just a slight bug.

Answer (score 4):

Here's my take: http://jsfiddle.net/WojtekKruszewski/Zf3m7/22/

Sometimes while moving mouse from popover trigger to actual popover content *diagonally*, you hover over elements below. I wanted to handle such situations – as long as you reach popover content before the timeout fires, you're save (the popover won't disappear). It requires `delay` option.

This hack basically overrides Popover `leave` function, but calls the original (which starts timer to hide the popover). Then it attaches a one-off listener to `mouseenter` popover content element's.

If mouse enters the popover, the timer is cleared. Then it turns it listens to `mouseleave` on popover and if it's triggered, it calls the original leave function so that it could start hide timer.

```
var originalLeave = $.fn.popover.Constructor.prototype.leave;
$.fn.popover.Constructor.prototype.leave = function(obj){
  var self = obj instanceof this.constructor ?
    obj : $(obj.currentTarget)[this.type](this.getDelegateOptions()).data('bs.' + this.type)
  var container, timeout;

  originalLeave.call(this, obj);

  if(obj.currentTarget) {
    container = $(obj.currentTarget).siblings('.popover')
    timeout = self.timeout;
    container.one('mouseenter', function(){
      //We entered the actual popover – call off the dogs
      clearTimeout(timeout);
      //Let's monitor popover content instead
      container.one('mouseleave', function(){
        $.fn.popover.Constructor.prototype.leave.call(self, self);
      });
    })
  }
};
```

Comment: Beware that this solution needs at least Bootstrap version 3.

Comment: This doesn't work if you're using the `container` option. I've fixed this in my fork: http://jsfiddle.net/5p7g4j22/1/

Comment: I like this solution, but what does this line do:



var self = obj instanceof this.constructor ?
    obj : $(obj.currentTarget)[this.type](this.getDelegateOptions()).data('bs.' + this.type)

Answer (score 1):

Finally I fix this problem. Popover disappear is because Popover not child node of link, it is child node of body.

So fix it is easy, change `bootstrap-twipsy.js` content:

change `.prependTo(document.body)` to `.prependTo(this.$element)`

and fix position problem cause by change.

and some use link tiger popover will cause popover with link too, so add a span contain link, so problem solved.

Comment: This works, albeit with some issues: 1 styling is inherited from the target 2. positioning is wrong elements in the topbar (I suspect it's to do with the floating)

Comment: So I said "fix position problem cause by change.".

Comment: How do you fix the position problems? It seems to work fine in Chrome/Safari but not in Firefox (ie the position of the popovers is bad in Firefox).

Comment: This solution is great if you're working with a simple site.  If you have a complex layout and other elements on the page using z-index, then you can quickly run into some big z-index headaches if you append the tooltip to the element and there is another element on the page that disrupts z-index stacking.

Comment: Please note: As of version 2.3.0 of Bootstrap you can define the container the Popover is appended to (http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#popovers). So the code Tinyfool is suggesting isn't needed anymore. However, in the case of appending it to a Anchor element itself, the whole Popover and its contents becomes a hyperlink.

Answer (score 1):

This is a version of Wojtek Kruszewski solution. This version handle popover blink when mouse go back to trigger. http://jsfiddle.net/danielgatis/QtcpD/

```
(function($) {
      var originalLeave = $.fn.popover.Constructor.prototype.leave;
      $.fn.popover.Constructor.prototype.leave = function(obj) {
        var self = (obj instanceof this.constructor ? obj : $(obj.currentTarget)[this.type](this.getDelegateOptions()).data("bs." + this.type));
        originalLeave.call(this, obj);
        if (obj.currentTarget) {
          var current = $(obj.currentTarget);
          var container = current.siblings(".popover");
          container.on("mouseenter", function() {
            clearTimeout(self.timeout);
          });
          container.on("mouseleave", function() {
            originalLeave.call(self, self);
          });
        }
      };

      var originalEnter = $.fn.popover.Constructor.prototype.enter;
      $.fn.popover.Constructor.prototype.enter = function(obj) {
        var self = (obj instanceof this.constructor ? obj : $(obj.currentTarget)[this.type](this.getDelegateOptions()).data("bs." + this.type));
        clearTimeout(self.timeout);
        if (!$(obj.currentTarget).siblings(".popover:visible").length) {
          originalEnter.call(this, obj);
        }
      };
    })(jQuery);
```

Comment: Beware that this solution needs at least Bootstrap version 3.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the solutions from @Wotjek Kruszewski and @danielgatis, but neither worked for me. Caveat: I'm using Bootstrap v2.1.0, not v3. This solution is in coffeescript (why are people still using plain javascript? =)).

```
(($) ->
  originalLeave = $.fn.popover.Constructor::leave
  $.fn.popover.Constructor::leave = (e) ->
    self = $(e.currentTarget)[@type](@_options).data(@type)
    originalLeave.call @, e

    if e.currentTarget
      container = $(".popover")
      container.one "mouseenter", ->
        clearTimeout self.timeout

        container.one "mouseleave", ->
          originalLeave.call self, e
) jQuery
```

Comment: Works flawlessly in 2.3.2 also, although I added `off('mouseenter')` to avoid ending up with more than one handler when showing and hiding the popover without moving the mouse inside it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what i did:

```
e = $("a[rel=popover]")
e.popover({
    content: d, 
    html:true, 
    trigger:'hover',
    delay: {hide: 500},
    placement: 'bottom',
    container: e, 
})
```

This is a very simple and awesone solution to this probelm, which i found out by looking into the bootstrap tooltip code. In Bootstrap v3.0.3 here is the line of code i noticed:

```
this.options.container ? $tip.appendTo(this.options.container) : $tip.insertAfter(this.$element)
```

this says that if `container` property of popover is defined then the popover gets appendTo() the element instead of insertAfter() the original element, all you need to do is just pass the element as container property. Because of appendTo() the popover becomes part of the link on which the hover event was binded and thus keeps the popover open when mouse moves on it.

Comment: Perfect work around, and without any buggy hacks. Well done, +1.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me on **BootStrap 3**:

```
el.popover({
  delay: {hide: 100}
}).on("shown.bs.popover", function(){
  el.data("bs.popover").tip().off("mouseleave").on("mouseleave", function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
      el.popover("hide");
    }, 100);
  });
}).on("hide.bs.popover", function(ev){
  if(el.data("bs.popover").tip().is(":hover"))
    ev.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the conversation linked by @stevendaniels is a link to a Twitter Bootstrap extension called [BootstrapX - clickover](http://blog.leecarmichael.com/2012/04/bootstrapx-clickover.html) by Lee Carmichael. This changes the popover from an overlarge tooltip into an interactive control, which can be closed by clicking elsewhere on the form, a close button, or after a timeout. Its easy to use, and worked very well for the project I needed it in. Some examples of its usage can be found [here](http://www.leecarmichael.com/bootstrapx-clickover/examples.html).

Answer (score 0):

I didn't like any of the answers I've found, so I combined some answers that were close to make the following code. It allows you to end up just typing `$(selector).pinnablepopover(options);` every time you want to make a 'pinnable' popover.

Code that makes things easy:

```
$.fn.popoverHoverShow = function ()
{
    if(this.data('state') !== 'pinned')
    {
        if(!this.data('bs.popover').$tip || (this.data('bs.popover').$tip && this.data('bs.popover').$tip.is(':hidden')))
        {
            this.popover('show');
        }
    }
};
$.fn.popoverHoverHide = function ()
{
    if (this.data('state') !== 'pinned')
    {
        var ref = this;
        this.data('bs.popover').$tip.data('timeout', setTimeout(function(){ ref.popover('hide') }, 100))
        .on('mouseenter', function(){ clearTimeout($(this).data('timeout')) })
        .on('mouseleave', function(){ $(this).data('timeout', setTimeout(function(){ ref.popover('hide') }, 100)) });
        this.on('mouseenter', function(){ clearTimeout($(this).data('timeout')) });
    }
};
$.fn.popoverClickToggle = function ()
{
    if (this.data('state') !== 'pinned')
    {
        this.data('state', 'pinned');
    }
    else
    {
        this.data('state', 'hover')
    }
};
$.fn.pinnablepopover = function (options)
{
    options.trigger = manual;
    this.popover(options)
    .on('mouseenter', function(){ $(this).popoverHoverShow() })
    .on('mouseleave', function(){ $(this).popoverHoverHide() })
    .on('click', function(){ $(this).popoverClickToggle() });
};
```

Example usage:

```
$('[data-toggle=popover]').pinnablepopover({html: true, container: 'body'});
```

Answer (score 0):

After seeing all Answer I made this I think it will be helpful .You Can manage Everything which you need.
Many answer doesn't make show delay I use this. Its work very nice in my project
/******
/*************************************************************/

```
<div class='thumbnail' data-original-title=''  style='width:50%'>    
 <div id='item_details' class='popper-content hide'>
    <div>
        <div style='height:10px'> </div>
        <div class='title'>Bad blood </div>
        <div class='catagory'>Music </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  HELLO POPOVER
</div>"
```

/****************SCRIPT CODE ****************** PLEASE USE FROM HEAR ******/

```
$(".thumbnail").popover({
trigger: "manual" ,
html: true,
animation:true,
container: 'body',
placement: 'auto right',
content: function () {
    return $(this).children('.popper-content').html();
}}) .on("mouseenter", function () {
var _this = this;

$('.thumbnail').each(function () {
    $(this).popover('hide');
});
setTimeout(function(){
    if ($(_this).is(':hover')) {
        $(_this).popover("show");
    }
},1000);
$(".popover").on("mouseleave", function () {
    $('.thumbnail').each(function () {
        $(this).popover('hide');
    });
    $(_this).popover('hide');
 }); }).on("mouseleave", function () {
    var _this = this;
    setTimeout(function () {
        if (!$(".popover:hover").length) {
            $(_this).popover("hide");
        }
    }, 100); });
```