# how to make twitter-bootsrap popover stay still when mouse is over it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using popover.

I used `delay : 1500` but yet I want it to stay for infinit time when the mouse hovers the baloon.

How can I achive this?

Comment: Doesn't appear to be built-in, so you'll have to build it yourself, I think. Take a look at the source code for [popover](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-popover.js) and [tooltip](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js) (which popover extends). It's basically all down to the `leave` method in tooltip

Comment: You may find this helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7703878/how-can-i-hold-twitter-bootstrap-popover-open-until-my-mouse-moves-into-it