# how to keep popover visible when i hover on the popover in full calendar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, fullcalendar

I have full calendar with some events. I have binded events from a json file. When i mouse hover on the particular event in the calendar it will show a popover. But when i move my mouse to the popover, the popover disappears. How to keep the popover visible when i move my mouse into the popover ? i have gone through other examples but didn't worked for me. 
[popover bootstap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15989591/how-can-i-keep-bootstrap-popover-alive-while-the-popover-is-being-hovered)

[link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18556355/is-there-a-way-to-keep-the-popover-displaying-when-hover-on-it-whith-hover-trig)

code :

```
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
//$.fn.popover.defaults.container = 'body';
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            contentHeight: 300,
            height: 200 ,
            eventRender: function(event, element) {
                element.popover({
                    title: event.title1,
                    placement: 'auto',
                    html: true,
                    trigger: 'hover',
                    animation:'true',
                    content: event.msg,
                    container: 'body'
                });
                $('body').on('click', function(e) {
                    if (!element.is(e.target) && element.has(e.target).length === 0 && $('.popover').has(e.target).length === 0)
                        element.popover('hide');
                });
            },
            events: eventData 
        });

    }
    });
```

Comment: No ideas ?? no one ??

Comment: make a fiddle, then we could do something.Okay

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if can be an acceptable solution for you, but as alternative you can consider to 'toggle' popover on eventMouseover:

```
eventMouseover: function (event, jsEvent) {
        $(this).popover({
            title: event.name,
            placement: 'right',
            trigger: 'manual',
            content: 'foo',
            container: '#calendar'
        }).popover('toggle');
    }
```

In this way popover stays on top until you re-hover on event (Bootstrap v3.3.2, FullCalendar v2.6.1).