# Getting popover to stay open with jquery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have some jquery code that looks like this:

```
// compile template through underscore templating       
var compiledTmpl = _.template(eventTemplate);

// configure popover settings and dynamic mark up
jQuery(this).closest(".item").popover({
   trigger:'manual',
   html:true,
   "content":compiledTmpl(eventData),
   "template": popoverTemplate
});

// show the popover
jQuery('.field-content').hover(function(){
    jQuery(this).closest(".item").popover('show');
});

jQuery(this).popover().mouseout(function (e) { 
    jQuery(this).closest(".item").popover('hide'); 
});
```

I would like to have to popover stay open when i go to mouse into it, but no matter what i try, it keeps hiding away. Does anybody have any idea why or can anyone possibly help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to figure out the solution to my issue from this post on SO:
[How can I keep bootstrap popover alive while the popover is being hovered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15989591/how-can-i-keep-bootstrap-popover-alive-while-the-popover-is-being-hovered/19684440#19684440)

Although it was not the marked answer as I did not see it fit to fully answering my question, I used the answer posted by @OkezieE :

Here is what my final code looked like:

```
// compile template through underscore templating       
var compiledTmpl = _.template(eventTemplate);
// configure popover settings and dynamic mark up
jQuery(this).closest(".item").popover({trigger:'manual', html:true,
   "content":compiledTmpl(eventData), "template": popoverTemplate})
// show the popover and allows popover to stay open on mouseenter
.on("mouseenter", function () {
    var _this = this;
    jQuery(this).popover("show");
    jQuery(".popover").on("mouseleave", function () {
        jQuery(_this).popover('hide');
    });
}).on("mouseleave", function () {
    var _this = this;
    setTimeout(function () {
        if (!jQuery(".popover:hover").length) {
            jQuery(_this).popover("hide");
        }
    }, 100);
});
```

I am going to mark this as my answer because it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the popover is not connected in anyway to the DOM element. So when you move your mouse, you're moving out of the trigger area. I'm having trouble envisioning a solution using mousein/mouseout, because the user needs to move from the trigger area to the popover, and there's 'dead space' between them.

What about changing to a click? Then the popover will be toggled by the click. Maybe put a delay on it, so it automatically closes after a certain amount of time. Another advantage of using click would be that touch users could see the popovers too.

Comment: I see what you are saying, I still feel that I will have to keep it as a hover option and on click would not work because it actually links to another page in addition to the hover option. I am open to using any other type of solutions if you may have any?

Answer (score 0):

You can try excluding the popover container from the mouseout:

```
jQuery(this).popover().mouseout(function (e) { 
    var target = $(e.target);
    if (!target.parents('.popover').length && !target.hasClass('.popover')) {
        jQuery(this).closest(".item").popover('hide'); 
    }
});
```

Comment: Sorry if the syntax is a little off, I'm not able to test this currently.

Comment: Your syntax seemed pretty spot on to me. Unfortunately, I still seem to get a similar result where the popover will display, but if i try to access anything inside the popover, it does not work. Do you have any other ideas?