# Bootstrap popover on hover keep alive - with generated element

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover

This works fine - using this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17997192/514416).  The popover is generated, and all is good..

```
$('[rel="popover"]').popover({
    html: true,
    //selector: '',
    trigger: 'manual',
    container: $(this).attr('id'),
    placement: 'top'
}).on("mouseenter", function () {
    var _this = this;
    $(this).popover("show");
    $(this).siblings(".popover").on("mouseleave", function () {
        $(_this).popover('hide');
    });
}).on("mouseleave", function () {
    var _this = this;
    setTimeout(function () {
        if (!$(".popover:hover").length) {
            $(_this).popover("hide")
        }
    });
});
```

However, I'm trying to adapt it so it works on mark up generated on the fly from Ajax calls.  This code seems to work(ish) but it appears the popover settings are not being used as all HTML is stripped.  Can anyone offer some advice? Much appreciated.

Edit: I've also tried adding `selector: '[rel="popover"]',` and still no luck

```
$('body').popover({
    html: true,
    //selector: '',
    trigger: 'manual',
    container: $(this).attr('id'),
    placement: 'top'
}).on("mouseenter", '[rel="popover"]', function () {
    var _this = this;
    $(this).popover("show");
    $(this).siblings(".popover").on("mouseleave", function () {
        $(_this).popover('hide');
    });
}).on("mouseleave",'[rel="popover"]', function () {
    var _this = this;
    setTimeout(function () {
        if (!$(".popover:hover").length) {
            $(_this).popover("hide")
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Please do not use "bootstrap" tag, use "twitter-bootstrap" since it means something else