# How to make bootstrap popover to remain visible while the popover is being hovered?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap 3 popovers and this code:

```
$('*[data-selfid]').mouseenter(function(event) {
            var e=$(this);
            e.popover({html:true,placement:'right',content:"Content: <a href="#">Link</a>"}).popover('show')
 // ajax query here //
});
```

It works, but popover disappears when the popover is being hovered

How to make bootstrap popover to remain visible while the popover is being hovered?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I keep bootstrap popover alive while the popover is being hovered?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15989591/how-can-i-keep-bootstrap-popover-alive-while-the-popover-is-being-hovered)

Comment: None of these answers worked for me...