# Keep showing popover beside svg while hovering the popover

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, svg

I want to keep the popover showing even when I hover on the popover. I already read this question [How can I keep bootstrap popover alive while the popover is being hovered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15989591/how-can-i-keep-bootstrap-popover-alive-while-the-popover-is-being-hovered), however in my case I use `svg` instead of `html`. Below is my current approach:

HTML:

```
<svg>
<circle id = "born" class = "medium" cx = "55%" cy = "60%" r = "15%"  stroke = "lightblue" stroke-width = "0.5%" fill = "url(#born)"/>
<svg>
```

jQuery:

```
$.fn.popover.Constructor.DEFAULTS.trigger = "hover";   // Set the default trigger to hover
$.fn.popover.Constructor.DEFAULTS.placement = 'right'; // Set the default placement to right
$.fn.popover.Constructor.DEFAULTS.html = true;
$.fn.popover.Constructor.DEFAULTS.container = "body";


$("circle#born").popover({
    title: "My Hello World!",
    content: "I was born in Tulung Agung, Indonesia. Back then, my mom presumed my mole as dirt, later on she realized that it would be my unique identifier."
}).on("mouseenter", function () {
    var _this = this;
    $(this).popover("show");
    $(this).parents("body").find(".popover").on("mouseleave", function () {
        $(_this).popover('hide');
    });
}).on("mouseleave", function () {
    var _this = this;
    setTimeout(function () {
        if (!$("body .popover:hover").length) {
            $(_this).popover("hide")
        }
    }, 100);
});
```

For further detail, check out my [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/6342/).. Thank you in advance..

Comment: What are you expecting `<circle id="born" ... fill="url(#born)"/>` to do? `url(#born)` is not a [valid paint specifier.](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/painting.html#SpecifyingPaint)

Comment: @squeamishossifrage That part doesn't matter.. The point here is how to keep showing the popover when I hovered on it. Check out my fiddle.

Comment: I did. The popover only appears when you hover over the thin outline of the circle because the circle isn't filled. Change `fill="url(#born)"` to `fill="white"`.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage hmm, that's not in my case. My problem is that when I try to hover on the popover dialog(dialog is showed after hovering on the circle), it got hidden. How can I keep it showing?