# Keep bootstrap3 popover alive while the popover is being hovered when content reloaded?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-popover

I'm trying to keep Bootstrap3 popovers alive while the popovers is being hovered. I'm using the JQuery code bellow suggested in OkezieE's answer from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15989591/how-can-i-keep-bootstrap-popover-alive-while-the-popover-is-being-hovered/32524596#32524596), and its working fine for standard use:

```
 $(".pop").popover({ trigger: "manual" , html: true, animation:false})
.on("mouseenter", function () {
    var _this = this;
    $(this).popover("show");
    $(".popover").on("mouseleave", function () {
        $(_this).popover('hide');
    });
}).on("mouseleave", function () {
    var _this = this;
    setTimeout(function () {
        if (!$(".popover:hover").length) {
            $(_this).popover("hide");
        }
    }, 300);
});
```

However, I have a sorting function that reloads the content using Ajax, and after the content is reloaded the popovers will not trigger. Anyone have a solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try, it should create a popover on any element with the selector `.pop` even if loaded after the DOM is loaded.

> If a selector is provided, popover objects will be delegated to the
>   specified targets. In practice, this is used to enable dynamic HTML
>   content to have popovers added. See this and an informative example.

```
$("body").popover({ selector: '.pop', trigger: "manual" , html: true, animation:false})
.on("mouseenter", function () {
    var _this = this;
    $(this).popover("show");
    $(".popover").on("mouseleave", function () {
        $(_this).popover('hide');
    });
}).on("mouseleave", function () {
    var _this = this;
    setTimeout(function () {
        if (!$(".popover:hover").length) {
            $(_this).popover("hide");
        }
    }, 300);
});
```

Comment: No success, popover not launching at all.

Comment: With trigger: "hover" your code works after the content is reloaded, but now the popover doesn't stay open on mouseenter.