# Enable bootstrap popovers everywhere and keep them open while they are being hovered

Tags: javascript, html, django, twitter-bootstrap

I found this result ([How can I keep bootstrap popover alive while the popover is being hovered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15989591/how-can-i-keep-bootstrap-popover-alive-while-the-popover-is-being-hovered)) that works for one of my popovers, but I have multiple popover events targeted by ID and am wondering how I can apply this either to all of them or to each one. Here is an example of some of the code snippets that I am using.

here is the html:

```
<label class="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" value="" />Body of Delusion<a data-bodyofdelusion="{% static 'pathfinder/html/sleepingGoddess/bodyOfDelusion.html' %}" data-toggle="popover" id="bodyOfDelusion">&#9660;</a>
</label>
<label class="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" value="" />Call the Soul's Blade<a data-callthesoulsblade="{% static 'pathfinder/html/sleepingGoddess/callTheSoulsBlade.html' %}" data-toggle="popover" id="callTheSoulsBlade">&#9660;</a>
</label>
```

Here is the javascript:

```
function loadContent(callTheSoulsBlade) {
    return $('<div>').load(callTheSoulsBlade, function (html) {
        parser = new DOMParser();
        doc = parser.parseFromString(html, "text/html");
        return doc.querySelector('h4').outerHTML + doc.querySelector('body').outerHTML;
    })
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#callTheSoulsBlade").popover({
        trigger: "hover focus",
        container: 'body',
        html: true,
        content: function () {
            return loadContent($(this).data('callthesoulsblade'))
        }
    });
});

function loadContent(bodyOfDelusion) {
    return $('<div>').load(bodyOfDelusion, function (html) {
        parser = new DOMParser();
        doc = parser.parseFromString(html, "text/html");
        return doc.querySelector('h4').outerHTML + doc.querySelector('body').outerHTML;
    })
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#bodyOfDelusion").popover({
        trigger: 'manual',
        container: 'body',
        html: true,
        animation: false,
        content: function () {
            return loadContent($(this).data('bodyofdelusion'))
        }
    }).on("mouseenter", function () { // This is the section from the link I provided.
        var _this = this;
        $(this).popover("show");
        $(".popover").on("mouseleave", function () {
            $(_this).popover('hide');
        });
    }).on("mouseleave", function () {
        var _this = this;
        setTimeout(function () {
            if (!$(".popover:hover").length) {
                $(_this).popover("hide");
            }
        }, 300);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to apply the behavior to all popovers, you can select them by their `data-toggle` attribute. And if you have a consistent naming for your `data-` attribute where you store the content URL, you can also easily find and load it from the common function.

```html
<label class="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" value="" />Body of Delusion<a data-staticurl="{% static 'pathfinder/html/sleepingGoddess/bodyOfDelusion.html' %}" data-toggle="popover" id="bodyOfDelusion">&#9660;</a>
</label>
<label class="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" value="" />Call the Soul's Blade<a data-staticurl="{% static 'pathfinder/html/sleepingGoddess/callTheSoulsBlade.html' %}" data-toggle="popover" id="callTheSoulsBlade">&#9660;</a>
</label>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
        trigger: 'manual',
        container: 'body',
        html: true,
        animation: false,
        content: function () {
            return loadContent($(this).data('staticurl'))
        }
    }).on("mouseenter", function () {
        var _this = this;
        $(this).popover("show");
        $(".popover").on("mouseleave", function () {
            $(_this).popover('hide');
        });
    }).on("mouseleave", function () {
        var _this = this;
        setTimeout(function () {
            if (!$(".popover:hover").length) {
                $(_this).popover("hide");
            }
        }, 300);
    });
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this only displays the link under the data-content field but not the file it is attached to.

Comment: @LillianErinFreeman I've changed the `data-` attribute name. Can you please check if it works for you now?

Comment: Thank you very much, so long as I included the DOMParser for each item it worked perfectly!!!!

Comment: Would you know a way to create a generic DOMParser? It seems that so long as I have 1, they all work. My Current code for that is included at the top.